# Erro ao instalar dependencia ou executar update no composer

Tags: php, composer, hhvm

Estou tendo um certo problema a instalar qualquer dependência usando o composer. Ja usei o *composer update* e o *composer update -v*. Preciso fazer testes em uma ferramenta de backup usando Laravel no momento. Porém em qualquer outra dependência que tento instalar aparece este erro abaixo.

> - This package requires php 7.2.18 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.

Este erro persiste mesmo tentando usar o *composer update*. Ja tentei atualizar o HHVM e também não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Aparentemente a versão do PHP contida no HHVM  é anterior a esta.

Comment: Ainda mesmo assim gera o mesmo erro. Tentei instalar a ultima versão. E mesmo assim persiste no erro.

Comment: @SkullFire Acabo de rever que a versão do php era posterior a versão do HHVM. Agradeço pela a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse problema dá devido ao versionamendo do PHP com o composer. Para isso deve entrar na pasta de seu projeto do Laravel e digitar `nano composer.json`. Em ***"require":{}***  mude a versão contida no ***composer.json*** para a versão atual do seu PHP. Recomendavel atualizar para a ultima versão do PHP.

```
   "require": {
            "php": "7.3.6",  //mudar a versão  
            "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
            "igorescobar/jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.14",
            "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    }
```